# How to read AjaxFileUploader file data in a webservice

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am using [AjaxFileUploader](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) jQuery plugin to upload files to the server.

I have the input fields on my HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload"  id="fileToUpload" />
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxFileUpload()" />
```

The ajaxFileUpload Javascipt code:

```
 $.ajaxFileUpload
(
    {
        url: 'http://localhost:23999/administration.asmx/UploadedFile',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                if (data.error != '') {
                    alert(data.error);
                } else {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
)

return false;
```

I also have a .NET webservice that is called from that plugin. I've checked and the webservice is indeed called.

My problem is that I don't know how to read the file data inside the webservice. I can't find and example for ASP.NET in the plugin instruction's page.

How can I access and read the posted file data in my ASP.NET webservice?

Comment: Have you checked this article - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757991/File-Upload-using-WCF-REST-API-and-JavaScript? Seems very close to what you need.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin, I prefer a ready-made solution which is fast to implement, that's why I've chosen the above plugin. WCF is an alternative solution if this doesn't work out. Thanks.